# jquery mobile form items on Android 2.3.6

Tags: android, forms, html, jquery-mobile, textfield

I have an application form with textfields and selectfield using jquery mobile 1.2.0 . I have tested my application on Ice-cream sandwich, Jelly bean and iOS. Works OK. But I cannot type anything in textfield or select a select field in Android 2.3.6 gingerbread.

Please suggest!

Comment: Append a little code where you think the problem might be at.

Comment: you might want to prepare a small example using http://jsfiddle.net...